# Use Kalman Filter to estimate position

Tags: position, kalman-filter, estimation

I try to use Kalman  filter in order to estimate the position. The input in the system is the velocity and this is also what I measure. The velocity is not stable, the system movement is like a cosine in general. So the equation is:
`xnew = Ax + Bu + w`, where:

> ```
> x= [x y]'
> A = [1 0; 0 1]
> B= [dt 0; 0 dt]
> u=[ux uy]
> w noise
> ```

As I mentioned, what I measure is the velocity. My question is how would the matrix C look like in the equation:

> y= Cx + v

Should I involve the velocity in the estimated states (matrix A)? Or should I change the equations to involve also the acceleration? I can't measure the acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to drop the velocities as inputs and put them in your state. This way, your state is both the position and velocity and your filter uses as observation both the measured speed of your vehicle and a noisy estimate of your position.

With this system your problem becomes:

```
x = [x_e y_e vx_e vy_e]'
A = [1 0 dt 0; 0 1 0 dt; 0 0 1 0; 0 0 0 1]
w noise
```

with x_e, y_e, vx_e, and vy_e the estimated values of the state

B is removed because u is 0. And then you have

```
y = Cx + v
with C = [1 0 0 0 ; 0 1 0 0 ; 0 0 1 0 ; 0 0 0 1]
```

With `y = [x + dt*vx ; y + dt*vy ; vx ; vy]` and x, y, vx, and vy the measured values of the velocities and x and y the position calculated with the measured velocities.

It is very similar to the example you will find [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter#Example_application.2C_technical) on Wikipedia

Comment: Thanks @Malcolm. I did something similar, but in my case I chose C=[0 0 1 0; 0 0 0 1] so that y= [vx vy]' , what do you think? But it does not work good. I believe that because we don't measure the position, we can not have the 'feedback' for it so that we can make a better new estimation. In addition to that, the velocity is not stable or predictable, usually it is random (although in most cases it is a cosine). Do you agree with this? I have not good knowledge of Kalman theory but from what I understood the states should be measurable (x y here, because is also contains the input vx and vy)

Comment: I think you hit the nail on the head. If you can't measure your state x and y then you're effectively only using the kalman filter on the velocities. However, this should still give you a good idea of the position so what do you mean by "it does not work good"?

Comment: the data is actually the rotation speed, coming from a gyro. I want to estimate/calculate the angle. In order to do this I integrate the gyro speed over time and this leads to a drift. I was trying to see if I can cancel the drift by using the Kalman filter as described above. And there is no improvement, so the angle estimation still drifts.

Comment: Ok that's different than what I was thinking. Do you have an IMU and accelerometers also?

Comment: Yes, I have it, magnetometer too. But I tried to use the Accelerometer and it does not give good result. More specific, it increases the angles a lot, so the result does not drift but is very inaccurate. I believe that this is happening because my system is accelerating in general (the movements I investigate are vibrations @5Hz, 10Hz etc), so I believe that this is the problem. That's why I tried to use a Kalman filter using gyro data only. But what is your remark on this, on the acceleration?

Comment: If you have both sensor and want to find the orientation of the IMU, doing sensor fusion between the accelerometer and gyro might be the best option: https://malcolmmielle.wordpress.com/2021/01/04/kalman-filter-for-sensor-fusion/

Comment: Thanks very much for the link. I have two questions/remarks: 1. Are you sure about the equations you are using to calculate the angles from the accelerometer? I believe they are a bit different. I also know that you can't use the accelerometer for calculate the yaw angle, for this you need the magnetometer. Do you agree?   2. Did you try to estimate the angle using data from a vibration, eg @5Hz? Because I tried something similar and as I mentioned, the angles are not accurate - probably because of the big accelerations.

Comment: I'm also learning, so I might have made mistakes :). 1) I just double checked and they indeed appear to be wrong. I don't remember where I got them from. Good catch I'll correct it. 1') AFAIK, you cannot calculate the yaw angle if your IMU z axis it parallels to the gravity vector and the IMU rotates around it. Hence why you need to use a magnetometer in that case. If your IMU is not aligned you don't have that pb (I think). 2) I haven't tried that I'm sorry :/. I don't have much input on that.

Comment: If your reference frame is not aligned* Not IMU

Comment: Hi Malcolm, again thanks!. Here is what I know: Regarding to the accelerometer, if the Z axis is parallel to the gravity, then the accelerometer will give (ideally) Accx,y=0, AccZ=1 g. So your angle will be zero. If you turn it (pitch or roll) then the accelerometer will not have zero for X,Y. Using this information you can find the pitch and roll angle. For the yaw is not possible because, if you turn the system around yaw(gravity) axis, the accelerometer values dont change. We compare the Acc X,Y,Z values to the gravity vector in order to find the angles, so your system shouldnt accelerating

Comment: The equations that I found for estimating the angles are: X -> Roll axis, Y->Pitch axis, Z->Yaw axis.  pitch angle=atan( -AccX / sqrt(AccY^2+AccZ^2) )   ,   Roll angle: I found two equations, they look to give similar result, but I am not 100% sure which one is the correct. 1. atan(AccY//Accz)  2. atan( AccY / sqrt(AccX^2 + AccZ^2) )  ,  Yaw Angle: Here you have to use the magnetometer